# Как после создания нужно уведомить клиента о назначенном пользователе, а пользователя о поступившем клиенте?

Tags: python, java, архитектура

Есть кейс создания клиента:

```
Controller -> CreateClientRequest -> CreateClientUseCase -> 
ClientEntity[assigned: UserEntity]
```

Клиенту назначается ответственный `assigned`.

После создания нужно уведомить клиента о назначенном пользователе, а пользователя о поступившем клиенте.

При этом у пользователя есть настройки уведомлений, например: e-mail, Push, SMS.

**Вопрос:**
Как реализовать такую агрегацию в чистой архитектуре?

Comment: А у пользователя есть настройки для всех клиентов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо использовать паттерн "наблюдатель", как раз предназначенный следить за изменениями в состоянии и оповещать другие классы (вызывать методы других классов).

А например у пользователя фабрикой создавать обьекты смс, пуш, имейл, и у них один интерфейс, один родитель, чей метод "послать сообщение" и будет вызываться.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста. 
Если уведомления вариативны, т.е. клиент может быть создан как самим менеджером (менеджера уведомлять не нужно), так и внешним источником, например с сайта (менеджера нужно уведомить). В таком случае где реализуется эта проверка в подписчике?

Comment: Вы при создании клиента в конструкторе клиента  добавляете к нему наблюдатель. Дальше либо конструктор можно вызывать с параметром - источник создания либо у вас будет фабрика, которая принимает источник создания и вызывает конструктор клиента, а после шлет сообщение если источник определенный